# I am using in rviz2 the tool nav2 goal. But I want to cancel the robot's navigation when it is at a distance of less than 2 meters from an obstacle

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to replicate this button but in a python code. The robot should stop if it is close <2 m from any obstacle. I know the functions BasicNavigator.cancelTask() works but just if you add the goal in code but I need to use the Nav2 Goal tool.

[image: image description]

I tried using the Simple Commander API just calling the BasicNavigator.cancelTask() function but is not working I think I am using wrong. Does anyone how to do it ? It should be calling a service but I do not know which one exactly.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3 
import rclpy
from nav2_simple_commander.robot_navigator import BasicNavigator
from rclpy.node import Node

from rclpy.action import ActionClient
from std_srvs.srv import SetBool

class StopNavigation(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('stop_navigation')
        # Create a BasicNavigator object.
        self.navigator = BasicNavigator()

    def stop_navigation_client(self):
        while rclpy.ok:
            self.navigator.waitUntilNav2Active()
            client = self.create_client(SetBool, "soft_stop_navigation")

            # Wait for the SetBool client to become available.
            while not client.wait_for_service(timeout_sec=1.0):
                rclpy.spin_once(self)

            # Send a request to the SetBool client.
            request = SetBool.Request()
            request.data = True
            future = client.call_async(request)
            rclpy.spin_until_future_complete(self, future)    

            # Check the response.
            response = future.result()
            print("")
            print("future_t: ", response.success)
            print("feedback: ",self.navigator.getFeedback())
            print("")
            if response.success:
                print("SetBool service succeeded, Cancel Nav.")
                self.navigator.cancelTask()

                # Check if the task was successfully canceled
                if self.navigator.cancelTask():
                    print("Task was successfully canceled")
                else:
                    print("Task could not be canceled")
                break
            else:
                print("Continue Nav...")
      
def main():
    # Initialize the ROS node.
    rclpy.init()

    # Create a MyNode object.
    node = StopNavigation()

    # Wait for the SetBool client to become available.
    node.stop_navigation_client()
    rclpy.spin_once(node)

    # Shutdown the ROS node.
    rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/415739/i-am-using-in-rviz2-the-tool-nav2-goal.-but-i-want-to-cancel-the-robot%27s-navigation-when-it-is-at-a-distance-of-less-than-2-meters-from-an-obstacle/) by [Juan Carlos](https://answers.ros.org/users/50383/juan-carlos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2023-05-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2023-05-24**:
Perhaps you should use [the SimpleGoalChecker](https://navigation.ros.org/configuration/packages/nav2_controller-plugins/simple_goal_checker.html) and modify its `xy_goal_tolerance` parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking over the `rclpy` API docs, unless there are functions undocumented, you cannot do that in python3, but you can in C++. You want to cancel all goals using `async_cancel_all_goals` even if they were sent from another client (e.g. rviz2).

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2023-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Juan Carlos](https://answers.ros.org/users/50383/juan-carlos/) on 2023-05-26**:
Thanks a lot, I use the action client `navigate_to_pose`. I just create the client and with the function `async_cancel_all_goals` I was able to stop the robot

```
rclcpp_action::Client<nav2_msgs::action::NavigateToPose>::SharedPtr cancel_navto_client = rclcpp_action::create_client<nav2_msgs::action::NavigateToPose>(node,"/navigate_to_pose");
    
cancel_navto_client->async_cancel_all_goals();
```